# How to extract CBC elapsed time in Pulp?

Tags: python, pulp, elapsedtime, coin-or-cbc

Is there any command to extract the CBC elapsed time with pulp?

With using `prob.solve(pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=True))` we can have the details of the process in the log. But I was wondering if there is any command to extract the elapsed time and write it into a file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question

Answer (score 3):

if you do `prob.solutionTime` you should get the time it took to solve the problem measured by pulp (not necessarily the one reported by CBC but probably close).

A complete example:

```
from pulp import *
prob = LpProblem("test", const.LpMinimize)
x = LpVariable("x", 0, 4)
y = LpVariable("y", -1, 1)
z = LpVariable("z", 0)
w = LpVariable("w", 0)
prob += x + 4 * y + 9 * z, "obj"
prob += x + y <= 5, "c1"
prob += x + z >= 10, "c2"
prob += -y + z == 7, "c3"
prob += w >= 0, "c4"
prob.solve()
print(prob.solutionTime)
```

If you want a way to parse the CBC log files, then you could check this library I made that returns a dictionary from a CBC, GUROBI or CPLEX log file: https://github.com/pchtsp/orloge

Comment: It worked, thanks. Does it give us (2/100)*(time in sec)? Since I ran a simple instance and the wall-clock time was around 4 seconds but it gave me time around 8 seconds. If so, we should multiply the result by `prob.solutionTime` by 50 in order to get the time in seconds. Am I right?

Comment: that's a good question! I was reading this https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time and I'm still not sure. In any case, that's what's being used by pulp.